# Case Statements and Percentages

Tags: plsql

Is it possible to insert a percentage formula inside a CASE statement in Oracle?  If so, has someone got any examples?

My percentage formula looks like this:

"Fact - People".Headcount/SUM("Fact - People".Headcount BY "Grade - Current"."Grade Equivalency", Calendar.Version)*100

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
CASE
  WHEN "Fact - People".Headcount/SUM("Fact - People".Headcount BY "Grade - Current"."Grade Equivalency", Calendar.Version)*100 = something THEN some_value
  ELSE some_other_value
END;
```